# How do I find my username and servername for windows SSH server

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh

I am currently testing SSH on my windows laptop and I followed this site to set up a SSH server on my pc:

[Getting started with OpenSSH](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse)

In the section "Connect to OpenSSH Server", what is the field "username" and "servername" referring to in the command:

```
ssh username@servername
```

How to I identity the username and servername of my own pc? I have tried commands like whoami or hostname and tried logging from another linux OS but did not work.

Also, is the command above windows client to windows server specific?

Comment: Is the machine connected to an AD directory?  What is the output of `[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name`, you are welcome to sanitize, if you wish.  Be sure you provide the machine name and the username from the output.  Is the client running the OpenSSH Server daemon?  Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: Add the output of the commands that you tried to your question.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is what you are expecting. `username` refers to the username on the remote system that you are trying to connect to. `servername` refers to the IP address of the remote system. *If you are on the same network with "name resolution i.e. DNS" then you can use the name for the machine rather than its IP address.*

Hence,

```
ssh username@servername
```

would map to

```
ssh [user-name-on-remote-sys]@[ip-address-of-remote-sys]
```

If your SSH server is on Windows, you can find the `username` and the `servername` by using powershell.

**username -**

```
$env:USERNAME
```

**servername -**

```
ipconfig | select-string  ('(\s)+IPv4.+\s(?<IP>(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))(\s)*') -AllMatches | %{ $_.Matches } | % { $_.Groups["IP"]} | %{ $_.Value }
```

For example, if the username is "jack" and the servername is "192.168.1.101", to connect from another machine you need to use the following,

```
ssh jack@192.168.1.101
```

Comment: Let us know if you are able to successfully ssh into your own server.

Comment: I'm getting connection time out, not sure the reason though.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the connection time out error message.

Comment: worked like a charm!!!